# How to pass integer and date in a node element for XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
public class XmlOutput1 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Employee");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
         rootElement.appendChild(getEmployee(doc, "1234", "Anupam", "Engineer", "AManager", "17/10/2014","10000","email"));
             rootElement.appendChild(getEmployee(doc, "1235", "Anirban", "Doctor", "BManager", "25/10/2014","20000","phone"));
             TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();            
             Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
             DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc); 
             StreamResult console = new StreamResult(System.out);
             StreamResult console1 = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\Users\\anupam.a.mukherjee\\Desktop\\anupam1.xml"));
             transformer.transform(source, console);
             transformer.transform(source,console1);
    }

    catch (Exception e) {          
         e.printStackTrace();

}
    }


private static Node getEmployee(Document document, String empno, String name, String job, String manager,String date,String salary,String communication) 
{
    Element employee = document.createElement("Employee");
     employee.setAttribute("empno", empno); 
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "name", name)); 
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "job", job));
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "manager", manager));
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "date", date));
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "salary", salary));
     employee.appendChild(getEmployeeElements(document, employee, "communication", communication));
     return employee;

}

private static Node getEmployeeElements(Document document, Element element, String name, String value) {       
Element node = document.createElement(name);        
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));        
return node;   
} 
private static Node getEmployeeElements1(Document document, Element element, int name, int value) {       
Element node = document.createElement(name);        
node.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value));        
return node;   

}
}
```

Now my question is in the second function that is getEmployeeElements1,its giving error,because node can accept only string,so please tell me the procedure to create node function of integer,date format,double..etc..

Answer (score 0):

- For the name: an Element is a Node, and the string expected as parameter is the tag name. It has no real sense to have a tag name as integer.
- For the value: DOM representation is minimal and does not handle advance typing, so you have to handle on your code the integer/date/double data checking, and store it as a String into the DOM document.

You can use frameworks that generate code and provide containers with typed data so that you are sure to store a correct value in a node (ex: [JAXB](https://jaxb.java.net/)), but while you use native DOM, you will have to manipulate only text data.

Here you can simply use methods like `static String Integer.toString(int i)` to fill you DOM object.